# What are Verts,NumVerts,Normals and TexCoords mean?

Tags: parameters, 3d, vuforia

I would like to know what are Verts,NumVerts,Normals and TexCoords mean for 3D model. In Vuforia SDK

Answer (score 1):

Verts essentially define the geometry of the model.
Normals describe the orientation of each face, they are used for shading calculations.
TexCoords are used to wrap the texture onto the model.

If you explained what you needed to know these parameters for, perhaps we could give you a better answer.